# with scram-sha-256 is password encrypted during authentication

Tags: postgresql

With the scram-sha-256 protocol, does Postgres server encrypt the client's password when initializing the connection so that authentication is secure and the password cannot be read?

Answer (score 1):

It is even better than encrypted, it is salted and hashed.  Not only can an eavesdropper not readily reverse it back to the raw password, the server can't either. A weakness though is that if you connect to a malicious server, it can simply insist on not using scram, and the default client will silently comply.